# Multiple uploads with carrierwave without javascript

Tags: ruby-on-rails, carrierwave

The idea is looping the image array in the controller then store each of them. The request shows correct info about uploaded images

```
{"utf8"=>"✓",
"authenticity_token"=>"usbr1ma8uKWBPiVFKh8AKoGYeaZTWAlLXscMBlFYyhw=",
"painting"=>{"name"=>"",
"image"=>[#<ActionDispatch::Http::UploadedFile:0x007fb414becad8 @original_filename="union_creek.jpg", @content_type="image/jpeg",
@headers="Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"painting[image][]\"; filename=\"union_creek.jpg\"\r\nContent-Type: image/jpeg\r\n",
@tempfile=#<File:/var/folders/80/2pcl195n7_x0l8bnrjrp4xw40000gn/T/RackMultipart20130105-7179-kr8a7e>>,
#<ActionDispatch::Http::UploadedFile:0x007fb414beca10 @original_filename="what_lies_beneath.jpg",
@content_type="image/jpeg",
@headers="Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"painting[image][]\"; filename=\"what_lies_beneath.jpg\"\r\nContent-Type: image/jpeg\r\n",
@tempfile=#<File:/var/folders/80/2pcl195n7_x0l8bnrjrp4xw40000gn/T/RackMultipart20130105-7179-iclmmw>>]},
"commit"=>"Create Painting",
"gallery_id"=>"13"}
```

However I got an misleading error when carrierwave attempts to store those of images

```
Called id for nil, which would mistakenly be 4 -- if you really wanted the id of nil, use object_id
```

The view

```
= form_for [@gallery, @gallery.paintings.new] do |f|
  %p= f.text_field :name, placeholder: "Enter painting name"
  %p= f.file_field :image, multiple: true
  %p= f.submit %>
```

The controller

```
uploader = ImageUploader.new
params[:painting][:image].each do |img|
  uploader.store!(img) # crash here
end
```

I see something wrong with the controller but I couldn't figure any better way to store multiple files with carrier.

Could anyone point me out ? Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is solution for anyone have the same problem

```
params[:painting][:image].map { |img| gallery.paintings.create(name: img.original_filename , image: img)
```

Comment: Is the problem settled? Tick the answer if it is! Also, if you have a repository, I would like to take a look. =)